# objective c UTF8String not working with japanese

Tags: objective-c, utf-8, nsstring

I would like to show the NSString below on my UILabel:

```
NSString *strValue=@"你好";
```

but i can not show it on my UILabel i get strange characters!

I use this code to show the text:

```
[NSString stringWithCString:[strValue UTF8String] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

I tried `[NSString stringWithCString:[strValue cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]` and it worked

but i can not show **emoticons** with `cStringUsingEncoding:NSISOLatin1StringEncoding` so i have to use `UTF8String`.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just use the `strValue` directly? What is the CString roundtrip supposed to achieve? And are you sure your source code file is in UTF-8? (And 你好's Chinese, btw)

Comment: does not show the text if i use it directly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your source file is in UTF-8, but the compiler you are using thinks it's ISO-Latin 1. What you think is the string `@"你好"` is actually the string `@"ä½ å¥½"`. But when you ask `NSString*` to give you this back as ISO-Latin 1, and treat it as UTF-8, you've reversed the process the compiler took and you end up with the original string.

One solution that you can use here is to tell your compiler what encoding your source file is in. There is a compiler flag (for GCC it's `-finput-charset=UTF-8`, not sure about clang) that will tell the compiler what encoding to use. Curiously, UTF-8 should be the default already, but perhaps you're overriding this with a locale.

A more portable solution is to use only ASCII in your source file. You can accomplish this by replacing the non-ASCII chars with a string escape using `\u1234` or `\U12345678`. In your case, you'd use

```
NSString *strValue=@"\u4F60\u597D";
```

Of course, once you get your string constant to be correct, you can ditch the whole encoding stuff and just use `strValue` directly.

Comment: it is utf8 by default as you said. So if it is utf8 then why it is not showing it?

Comment: @stefanosn: Perhaps you have a compiler flag set that's changing the input charset, or a locale set somewhere. Have you tried just using the `\u` escapes? That's the most portable solution

Comment: You could also try going the NSLocalizedString route and put the text into a Strings file. That keeps it out of the source file, too, so maybe UTF-8 survives your setup then.

Comment: Anyway thanks guys i will keep searching. The one Kevin sais it is a solution so i will accept it.

Comment: stringWithUTF8String did the job also for those who are struggling